# Cassandra bin/sstable2json results in malformed JSON (randomly produces consecutive commas)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm currently using bin/sstable2json and running into issues with the conversion process. A successfully-converted SSTable will result in JSON files containing these:

["5665275509643149313","0b000100000010d...moar hex",1350706937228001]

but occasionally I encounter these types of rows in the output:

["5665275509643153409","0b000100000010d36..., , ,     , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

The rows do not have closing brackets or the closing long, and the serialized hex string will not have a closing quote. They also normally end in '9343300' but the serialized hex string in failed rows will not have the closing bytes.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: What is your schema for this CF?  If you can easily reproduce the issue, I suggest opening a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA.

Comment: Not easily reproduced, so I'm going to move on for now. Thanks!